# JSONLint always fails validation

Tags: json, validation

I have JSON file with up to 1,500 items. Apparently, there is an error.
I have taken the first and last fields and tried to validate it. I have copied and pasted the below code, but I'm getting errors.

```
[{
    "username" : "testuser0",
    "date_added" : "04/07/13", 
    "description" : "Desc"
},
{
    "username" : "testuser1",
    "date_added" : "04/07/13", 
    "description" : "Desc"
}];
```

And this is what it says, even though I don't think there's anything wrong with it:

> Parse error on line 12: ...ion": "Desc"    }];
>   ---------------------^ Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'

Comment: Take out the semicolon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the trailing semi-colon ;
It shouldn't be there for JSON (it is not javascript)